# Update a row of a dataframe based on a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame having these columns:

```
df.columns = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', ...]
```

Now, I want to update each row of my df using a dictionary:
let us say that I have this dictionary for the first row:

```
dic_ = {'May':3, 'Jul':8}
```

How can I update each row of df using the above dictionary? Please note that this dictionary is different for each row and it does not include all columns of df.

Comment: Please can I ask what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `assign` here:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'])
print(df)
df_updated = df.assign(**pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic_,orient='index').T)
print(df_updated)
```

---

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May]
Index: []

   Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jul
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    3    8
```

Comment: How should I update the second row? I think this code does not work

Comment: May be add an example to frame the question better